# Remove Specific Part of String when Multiple Split Characters are used

Tags: r

I have read a few Q&As on removing and splitting strings, but what I have not come across is removing a section by splitting w/ a specific character, when that character is used more than once in a string. For instance,

```
 V <- c("TUAA_2124_5733", "GAMS_1236_4767")
 V1 <- sapply(strsplit(V, split='_', fixed=TRUE), function(x) (x[2]))
 V1
 V1 [1] "2124" "1236"
```

This section removes the first section separated by the underscore and the last section as well.

```
 sapply(strsplit(V, split='_', fixed=TRUE), function(x) (x[2]))
```

How can I keep the last two sections (2124_5733 & 1236_4767), separated by the underscore, while removing only the first section (TUAA & GAMS).

Thanks!

Comment: `sub('.*?_', '', V)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gsub` will do this with the right regular expression.

```
gsub("^.*?_", "", V)
[1] "2124_5733" "1236_4767"
```

This expression can be understood like this:

The initial ^ means the beginning of the string.
. means any character, and .* means zero or more instances of any character. 
However, the default is "greedy matching", so .* would match all characters up to the last _.  We want the first one,  so we use `.*?` which suppresses the greedy matching and will only match up to the first `_`. So putting it all together,  `^.*?_` starts at the beginning of the string, matches any number of characters up to and including the first _. These are replaced with nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This worked as written. Could you explain the special characters? Also will this work if one of those first 4 characters is a number? Any short description would be fruitful! Thanks!

Comment: Just `sub` will do it as it is a single replacement.

Comment: @thelatemail is right. `sub` will do this as well as `gsub` and probably make a little more sense since the expression can only possibly match once.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code helps --

```
sub(pattern = "\\w{1,4}_", replacement = "", V)
```

Comment: If any of those first characters can be  number, better to use                                                                                                                 sub(pattern = "[[:alnum:]]{1,4}_", replacement = "", V)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This was more practical for my specific use case.